# Show differents views on same page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page on my `Ionic2` project, and I want to show other stuff when user press a button, I made it with `booleans` and I'm not sure if it's a good aproach or not... I have plently of `*ngIf` on my `.html` so I'm wondering whats the better way to change the view without creating another page, only changing the `.html` code, could you give to me an example?

I used to to this with `booleans` but now, I've faced that I have components on my `<ion-header>`, `<ion-content>` and on my `<ion-footer>` and I don't want to make an `*ngIf` on every component...

I'm using >= `Angular2` and >= `Ionic2`

Some code, I don't have put all of my code because it's quiet large, so I put more or less how do I have structurated the code:

```
  <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title *ngIf="view1">{{title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
 <p *ngIf="view1">SomeMoreStuff</p>

</ion-header>

<!-- view 1 -->

  <div *ngIf="view1">
      <!-- more stuff -->
  </div>


</ion-content>
<ion-footer *ngIf="view1">

</ion-footer>
```

Now I have another `boolean` called `view2` to show different `footer`, `ion-title`, etc...

Comment: Please show the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed. It sounds like 2 `*ngIf` should do, but it's hard to tell from the information you provided.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Edited...

Comment: generally this sounds like a correct approach. you could also create separate components for your header, content and footer. but as Günter Zöchbauer said, it's hard to tell with code examples.

Comment: I see. I would recommend to create separate, reusable components for header, content and footer. then you can pass the view identifier as an @Input attribute.

Comment: I would use only one variable to control what view should be shown and use `*ngIf="view1"` and `*ngIf="!view1"`. If you don't want to add `*ngIf` on every component wrap the whole view with `<ng-container *ngIf="view1">...</ng-container>` (with the additional `!` for the 2nd view for "not") and put inside each of these two containers the whole content of the respective view. Then you only have 2 `*ngIf`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the problem is if I need for example view3, right?....

Comment: Then use a String instead of boolean and use `*ngIf="view == 'view1'` or `*ngIf="view == 'view3'`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you post an answer doing this : `wrap the whole view with <ng-container *ngIf="view1">...</ng-container>` you mean add EVERYTHING inside of ng-container from view1 and create another for view2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole view in a container

```
<ng-container *ngIf="view == 'view1'">
 <!-- view 1 goes here -->
<ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="view == 'view2'">
 <!-- view 2 goes here -->
<ng-container>
```

If you have shared parts between different views, either keep them outside the `<ng-container *ngIf="...">` or move them into reusable components and add them where needed.